# One TCHAR member in one C struct - how to dynamically allocate member and array of struct?

Tags: c, struct

I have this struct:

```
struct sArray {
TCHAR *sName;
};
```

I want to now dynamically allocate memory for an array of sArray, and also dynamically allocate memory for sName. So I can use something like var[0].sName, var[1].sName...var[x].sName.

I'm looking for a simple solution - tons of articles here and on the web about dynamic allocation, but none answer this.

So, how do I do this? And how do I free the member and array memory when done with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int len = 20; //number of elements (sArray's) you want in ar.
struct sArray *arr = malloc(length*sizeof(struct sArray));
int i;
int nameLength = 30; // max length of name
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    arr[i].sName = malloc(nameLength*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

and to free the memory:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    free(arr[i].sName);
free(arr);
```

Comment: When you say "whatever length you want for the array" in "int len = 20;" do you mean the amount of elements in the array?

Comment: Why is it arr[i].sName and not arr[i]->sName?

Comment: because arr[i] is not a pointer, you only use `->` when accessing a member of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// +1 for the NULL terminal byte
TCHAR *names = (TCHAR *)calloc(1, (maxNameLen+1) * NumberOfNames);
struct sArray *array = (struct sArray *)malloc(numberOfArrays);
array[0].sName = names[0];
...
...

free(names);
free(array);
```